# Is this the right community for this type of question + latex support

Tags: discussion, support, status-completed, scope, formatting

I posted [this question](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/12134/confused-about-time-systems-in-ephemeris-computation-from-gps-subframes) on *robotics.stackexchange* because the lack of latex support for *gis.stackexchange* made me wonder whether or not it was the appropriate community to ask such questions. So I actually have two questions: do you think that this question is more appropriate where it was posted, or would *gis.stackexchange* be a better option? Second, will there be any latex support (well, maybe there already is, but it just is not accessible through the usual syntax?)?

Answer (score 4):

> do you think that this question is more appropriate where it was
>   posted, or would gis.stackexchange be a better option?

I'm not sure GIS SE would be a *better* option here, for two reasons:

1. The actual problem doesn't appear to be about GIS specifically - To me it appears you're asking about what parts of a formula means (correct me if I'm wrong), which leads me to...
2. Mathematics SE may be a good option *if* Robotics SE isn't the right one for your question.

That all said, I may be way off as I really didn't understand much of what you wrote, and if so hopefully some of our more knowledgeable users can weigh in here by posting an answer.

> Second, will there be any latex support (well, maybe there already is,
>   but it just is not accessible through the usual syntax?)?

Unlikely - there's been no call for it (that I'm aware of), and because of [There's seriously no reason why LaTeX markup via MathJax shouldn't be enabled on SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252282/theres-seriously-no-reason-why-latex-markup-via-mathjax-shouldnt-be-enabled-on) - specifically Nick Craver's answer.